# Check if two cells match specific values to create MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check if two cells have two different values. I want to create a `MsgBox` for when if cell `A1` is `A` and `B1` is `B` to create `MsgBox` with text. But that the `MsgBox` will only pop up once.

The code works when I have one cell:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oldVal
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Target.Address = "$A$1") Then
        If Target.Value = "A" And Target.Value <> oldVal Then
            oldVal = Target.Value
            MsgBox "Text."
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

But I get error message when I try to for two cells:

> Compile error: Procedure declaration does not match description of
>   event or procedure having the same name.

```
Option Explicit

Dim oldVal
Dim oldVal2
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target1 As Range, ByVal Target2 As Range)
    If (Target1.Address = "$A$1") And (Target2.Address = "$B$1") Then
        If Target1.Value = "A" And Target2.Value = "B" And Target1.Value <> oldVal And Target2.Value <> oldVal2 Then
            oldVal = Target1.Value
            oldVal2 = Target2.Value
            MsgBox "Text."
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

What can I do?

Comment: You'll need to check if your `Target` intersects with `A1:B1` rather than the way you try now, e.g: `If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:B1")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub`. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)

Comment: @JvdV I need to point out that `A1` and `B1` are just simplication of the cells. In reality the cells are `E10`` and `F7` and the values I want to match are unique values, not `A` or `B`. Would your solution still work except I have to change `Range("A1:B1")`.

Comment: You could use `UNION` to merge the two cells in a range before you try intersect that range with `Target`. You can also omit this, using a comma in between cells. These values you talking about can just be variables I'm sure. See below answer of @Peh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you cannot change the parameters of the [Worksheet.Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) and add more than one `Target` like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target1 As Range, ByVal Target2 As Range)
'this does not work!
```

Instead you need to check if the `Target` intersects ([Application.Intersect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect)) with your desired range and then check the values of A1 and B1.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1,B1")) Is Nothing Then 'check if A1 or B1 changed
        If Me.Range("A1").Value = "A" And Me.Range("B1").Value = "B" Then
            MsgBox "A1=A and B1=B"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```